# IOS: NSString split

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, split

I have this `NSString`:

```
NSString *perc = @"- 20 %";
```

I want only "20 %".

What can I do?

Comment: This is a "read the Documentation" question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[perc subStringFromIndex:2];
```

There are different functions for substrings, take a look at them either typing *"subString"* and getting xcode help, or in traditional way - from doc :)